# mysqli packages dont seem to work for php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i cannot get mysqli_connect to work. most solutions to this problem suggests i have an old version of php which doesnt support it.  my version is brand new and up to date and also ive tried a variety of older versions of php over the past 24 hours to see if i can make this work. no.

#########

below is the line that causes the problem (ive tried many variations of this ie "mysqli" , "MySQLi" , "mysqli_connect" etc...)

```
<?php
$connection=MySQLi("localhost","root","password","ids");
?>
```

below is the error i always get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli_connect" not found in C:\Users\User\Downloads\New folder (6)\php-8.0.7-nts-Win32-vs16-x86\main.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
```

###########

i tried making this line in php.ini

```
;     extension=/path/to/extension/mysqli.so
```

to the line below  (since thats what the documentation suggests you do for unsupported versions)

```
extension=C:\Users\User\Downloads\New folder (6)\php-8.0.7-nts-Win32-vs16-x86\ext\php_mysqli.dll;
```

but that didnt work.

##############

the documentation is extremely unhelpful and simply asserts that mysql should work by default for newer versions of php ... well it doesnt for me.

can someone please point me in the right direction. why does mysqli not work for me?

##############

extra info that might be helpful.

im on windows 10.

i have mysqlworkbench (ive tried this with my workbench server both running and shutdown.)

i can echo back hello world so php itself works

Comment: Nah, that’s probably not how you should specify an extension path … There should be an `extension_dir` set somewhere before this, go check what that is, and then place the extension DLL in there. And then specify the relative path from that folder after `extension=`

Comment: There's no class called `mysqli_connect` in PHP. There's also no such class being used in your code. Please clarify your question. Also, this seems wrong `$connection=MySQLi`